# Date interval filter

Tags: sql, date, presto

I have a filter in my query such as:

```
 where business_day BETWEEN date_add('day',-14, CURRENT_DATE) AND date_add('day',-2,CURRENT_DATE)
```

How can I tweak this to where it is just 14 days prior to current date and not 14 days from 2 days prior? Just replacing -2 with 0 in latter part of clause as:

```
where business_day BETWEEN date_add('day',-14, CURRENT_DATE) AND date_add('day',0,CURRENT_DATE)
```

or would there be cleaner way for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This expression is a no-op:

```
date_add('day',0,CURRENT_DATE)
```

It actually returns `CURRENT_DATE`.

I find that date arithmetics is easier to undersand using the `interval` syntax. If you have no dates in the future, you can do:

```
where business_day >= current_date - interval '14' day
```

If there are dates in the future, then:

```
where business_day >= current_date - interval '14' day and business_day <= current_date
```